# http://localhost:4200/ says "This site can’t be reached"

Tags: angular

The local development server has been compiled successfully however the localhost http://localhost:4200/ says This site can’t be reached, localhost refused to connect.

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

√ Compiled successfully.
PS E:\Angular projects\Test Project 1\cwh-todo-list>

Comment: Add a bit more of information, maybe screenshot or copy/paste the logs, version of Angular, cli, NodeJS. This is too vague to be able to help you.

Comment: How are you running angular? Paste the command that you use

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: make sure your base url is set.  what does your browser console tab say?